# Monitoring SOAP with zabbix

Tags: soap, monitoring, zabbix

As i understand from documents, zabbix has made it possible to monitor SOAP web service by using custom headers from v2.4. but it has no clear explanation on how to do this!!can anyone explain more about this?

UPDATE: i have SOAP web service on a port on my localhost.can i monitor it's performance using zabbix 2.4?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP request usually needs custom header, e.g.:

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml
```

You can define this custom header(s) in the Zabbix 2.4 Webmonitoring. But keep in mind, that Webmonitoring is executed from the Zabbix server (or proxy) only. Make sure, that your soap server is reachable from the Zabbix server (proxy) and only then you can use Webmonitoring. Otherwise (if service is localhost only) you have to use checks, which are executed from the zabbix agent (net.tcp.service.perf, UserParameters) and in that case you can have a problem with headers.

It depends how deeply you want to monitor your SOAP service. If it's only http connection time, then you don't need a Webmonitoring (net.tcp.service.perf is enough). If you want create some special SOAP request with response content check, then Webmonitoring is right choice for you.

Docs:

- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/web_monitoring
- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent

Comment: Do you know how can i do the same with opennms?is it even possible?